# Get specific fields in Bulk API success file

Tags: bulk-api-v2

How to retrieve  only sf_id and externalID from below uri.

services/data/v41.0/jobs/ingest/{jobid}/successfulResults/

I created a batch job, uploaded data, completed job and got results and I got all the fields in success file. How to get only sf_id and externalId in success file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk API V2 provides no customizability in its results files.

The format is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/get_job_successful_results.htm) to include all columns from the input CSV. It does not accept options; you cannot change the format of the output file.

Note that the results [format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_bulk_v2/asynch_api_batches_get_results.htm) for Bulk API V1 is completely different and does not include the original input data, only the Salesforce Id and the outcome of the operation.